# Editing data from database in textbox which are taken from subform

Tags: ms-access, vba

In my form I have a subform, which displays A, B, C.
Then information C is displayed in textbox. User should have a possibility to modify this data in order to modify data in database.

I am able to display information C in text box based on this subform. However it is uneditable, it is written: **"Control can't be edited; it's bound to the expression"**.

It seems to me, that it is impossible to edit data because it is taken not directly from database but from sub form, so I make special query which takes data directly from database however I lose an event which is based on selecting proper record from subform (there is only onEnter and onExit events)

Is it possible to make such things?

Comment: Does the data table exist in MS Access, is it a linked table, or is the data coming from a query?

Comment: subform is made from query based on existing in MS Access tables.

Comment: If the answer below doesn't solve your problem, check out additional reasons why your recordset might not be updateable: http://rogersaccessblog.blogspot.com/2009/11/this-recordset-is-not-updateable-why.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, There is a solutions to my problem:
http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/950422-editing-data-database-textbox-taken-subform

Thank You for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a second subform to contain the `C` text box.  Link the second subform to the first with the underlying table's primary key.

That's the easiest alternative I can think of to make the text box editable.

Comment: Thank You,
At this moment I am closest to Your solution, however I'd prefer an option with text box, because info C is quite long.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a recordset to populate or modify anything, then make sure you are using the `.Edit` and `.Update` to modify an existing cell in a row.

```
Dim myR as Recordset

Set myR = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Table_Name_Here", dbOpenDynaset)

'use a .FindFirst method to find the row you want to modify
'or modify the Recordset to pull a SELECT statement instead of the whole table

myR.Edit
myR![Field_to_edit] = Forms![main form name]![subform control name].Form![control name]
myR.Update

Set myR = Nothing
```

Comment: After displaying data from subform in textbox I can't write in it anything. It looks like locked.
Data in text box are written by ControlSource = [subForm]![column]

Comment: I received Message "Control can't be edited; it's bound to the expression '[subFrom]![Column]"

Comment: Data from 'C' is displayed in both C text field in subform, and also displayed in the main form in a text field?  Sorry, I thought you just needed the information from the subform to edit the data in the table.

Comment: Actually, C text in subform is hidden. It is used only fo displaying it in text box. It is quite long text and also for looking more estetic I'd prefer to use a text box